# Error while creating an optimized production build...it is unable to compile

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, compilation, npm-start

C:\Users\deshm>cd\REACT\project-test

C:\REACT\project-test>npm run build

But it did not compile

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './logo.avg' in 'C:\REACT\project-test\src'
[cmd IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB8r6.png)